# html5-canvas drawing curve on move of slider

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Hi I want to draw a curve as I move slider. I have two kinds of curves. Bezier curve and quadratic cruve. Also As I draw the curve I want to move an object on that same path. I want it to be dynamic so If I should be able to change the curve points. 
So I need a function which I can call on the slider change as I am doing for line.
Here is my code. This code will work only in chrome.

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

                    <style type="text/css">
                        .wrapper {
                            margin: 0 auto;
                            width: 1000px;
                        }
                        .canHdr {
                            float: left;
                            width: 450px;
                            height: 400px;
                            border: 1px solid red;
                        }
                    </style>

                </head>
                <body>
                    <form>
                        <!-- wrapper -->
                        <div class="wrapper">

                            <!-- canHdr -->
                            <div id="canHdr" class="canHdr" >

                                <p>
                                    This is my 1st div with quadratic curve I want to draw this curve as I move the slider. I want to make it dynamic so when I should be able to change the curve points. Also I want to move an object on that curve as I am doing in my 3rd div.
                                </p>

                                <div class="canOuterHdr" >
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="300" height="195" style="position: relative;">
                                        [No canvas support]
                                    </canvas>

                                </div>

                                <div id="slider1" class="newBg">
                                    <input id="slide1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange="counterSlider('slide1');" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!--/ canHdr -->
                            <!-- canHdr2 -->
                            <div id="canHdr2" class="canHdr" >

                                <p>
                                    This is my 2nd div. I have bezier curve. I want to make it dynamic so when I should be able to change the curve points. Also I want to move an object on that curve as I am doing in my 3rd div.
                                </p>

                                <div class="canOuterHdr" >
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" height="195" style="position: relative;">
                                        [No canvas support]
                                    </canvas>

                                </div>

                                <div id="slider2" class="newBg">
                                    <input id="slide2" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange="counterSlider('slide2');" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- canHdr2 -->
                            <!-- canHdr3 -->
                            <div id="canHdr3" class="canHdr" >
                                <p>
                                    This is my 3rd div with slanting line. I want to move a ball on this line when I move the slider. So as the line increases ball will also move on the line.
                                </p>

                                <div class="canOuterHdr" >
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas3" width="300" height="195" style="position: relative;">
                                        [No canvas support]
                                    </canvas>

                                </div>

                                <div id="slider3" class="newBg">
                                    <input id="slide3" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange=" drawSlopeCurve2('slide3','100'); " />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!--/ canHdr3 -->
                            <!-- canHdr4 -->
                            <div id="canHdr4" class="canHdr" >

                                <p>
                                    This is my 4th div with slanting line. I want to move a ball on this line when I move the slider. So as the line increases ball will also move on the line.
                                </p>

                                <div class="canOuterHdr" >
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas4" width="300" height="195" style="position: relative;">
                                        [No canvas support]
                                    </canvas>

                                </div>

                                <div id="slider4" class="newBg">
                                    <input id="slide4" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange=" drawSlopeCurve1('slide4','100'); " />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!--/ canHdr4 -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- /wrapper -->

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            newSprite('myCanvas3', 16, 170);
                            quadraticCurve('myCanvas1', 18.8, 45, 28, 160, 228, 165);
                            bezierCurve('myCanvas2', 20, 75, 55.2, 150.0, 200,100, 228, 165)
                            function counterSlider(sID) {

                                var slideVal = document.getElementById(sID).value;
                                /*if (maxValue ==100){

                                 slideVal=slideVal/100;
                                 }*/
                                slideVal = slideVal / 100;

                                if (slideVal == 0) {

                                /*  erase('myCanvas2');
                                    erase('myCanvas3');
                                    erase('myCanvas4');*/
                                    //newSprite('myCanvas1b', 18.8, 45);
                                    newSprite('myCanvas3', 16, 170);

                                } else if (slideVal > 0 && slideVal <= 34) {

                                    /*erase('myCanvas1');
                                    //erase('myCanvas1b');
                                    erase('myCanvas2');
                                    erase('myCanvas3');
                                    erase('myCanvas4');*/

                                } else if (slideVal > 34 && slideVal <= 67) {

                                    /*erase('myCanvas1');

                                    erase('myCanvas2');
                                    erase('myCanvas3');
                                    erase('myCanvas4');*/

                                } else if (slideVal > 67 && slideVal <= 100) {

                                    /*erase('myCanvas1');

                                    erase('myCanvas2');
                                    erase('myCanvas3');
                                    erase('myCanvas4');*/

                                }
                            }

                            function erase(canvasId) {

                                var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
                                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                                context.beginPath();
                                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                                canvas.width = canvas.width;

                            }

                            /**********for backgroundImage********************/

                            function quadraticCurve(canId, spx, spy, cpx, cpy, endx, endy) {

                                var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);
                                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                                ctx.beginPath();
                                ctx.moveTo(spx, spy);
                                ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cpx, cpy, endx, endy);
                                ctx.strokeStyle = "#eaca2d";
                                ctx.stroke();

                            }

                            function bezierCurve(canId, spx, spy, cpx1, cpy1, cpx2, cpy2, endx, endy) {

                                var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);
                                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                                ctx.beginPath();
                                ctx.moveTo(spx, spy);
                                ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cpx1, cpy1, cpx2, cpy2, endx, endy);
                                ctx.strokeStyle = "#eaca2d";
                                ctx.stroke();

                            }

                            function newSprite(canId, mvx, mvy) {
                                var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);
                                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                                //ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
                                ctx.beginPath();
                                ctx.fillStyle = "#0077c1";
                                ctx.arc(mvx, mvy, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                                ctx.closePath();
                                ctx.fill();
                            }

                            function drawSlopeCurve1(sID, maxValue) {
                                // erase('canvasTwo');

                                var canId = 'myCanvas4';
                                var slideVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(sID).value);
                                var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);
                                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                                canvas.width = canvas.width;
                                //line end points
                                x1 = 16;
                                y1 = 170;
                                x2 = 200;
                                y2 = 80;

                                //get slope (rise over run)
                                var m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
                                //get y-intercept
                                var b = y1 - (m * x1);
                                //get distance between the two points
                                var distance = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
                                //get new x and y values
                                var x = x1 + parseInt(distance / maxValue * slideVal);
                                var y = parseInt(m * x + b);

                                context.beginPath();
                                context.moveTo(x1, y1);
                                context.lineTo(x, y);
                                context.lineWidth = 0.6;
                                context.stroke();

                                newSprite(canId, x, y);
                            }

                            function drawSlopeCurve2(sID, maxValue) {
                                // erase('canvasTwo');

                                var canId = 'myCanvas3';
                                var slideVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(sID).value);
                                var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);
                                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                                canvas.width = canvas.width;
                                //line end points
                                x1 = 16;
                                y1 = 170;
                                x2 = 160;
                                y2 = 72;

                                //get slope (rise over run)
                                var m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
                                //get y-intercept
                                var b = y1 - (m * x1);
                                //get distance between the two points
                                var distance = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
                                //get new x and y values
                                var x = x1 + parseInt(distance / maxValue * slideVal);
                                var y = parseInt(m * x + b);

                                context.beginPath();
                                context.moveTo(x1, y1);
                                context.lineTo(x, y);
                                context.lineWidth = 0.6;
                                context.stroke();

                                newSprite(canId, x, y);
                            }

                        </script>
                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>
```

This is link for jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QRVxH/

Comment: What have you tried? You already have the code for drawing curves, so just change the values when the slider changes, you've already written the handler for slider values changing.

Answer (score 1):

You should begin by defining the curve in a function, so you can calculate where the graph should end for each x-position. Then you also know where to draw the end-dot.

My demo function has a function to draw a sine on the canvas:

```
function calc(x){
    var y = 100 + ( 50*Math.sin(x*400));
    return y;
}
```

By drawing a line (not a curve!) between the points you get your graph.

```
for (var x=0; x<=400 && (x <= slider.value); x+=3){        
    y= calc(x);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w1ll3m/CbjWK/11/

Added [html5slider.js](https://github.com/fryn/html5slider) to make the slider work in firefox.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I have got the code which is drawing the curve. But it is not as smoothly drawing as your. Can any one help to make it work smoothly? Also I want to move an object on the same curve. And Last question how can i make this work in bezier curve. My working js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/JGz4T/1/

Comment: Your code has multiple paths (if/else with point sets), that does not make it easier! Define your line in an equation like `y=3x^2` or `y=cos(x)` so you can simply pick your x to calculate your y. That way you can draw a point in steps of 1 to 4 pixels (x-axis). http://jsfiddle.net/w1ll3m/JGz4T/4/ see my red line!

Comment: Can you explain me the equation you have used to get the points? also I am trying to start the slider at 0 position but it is going to the end position.

Comment: The equation is plain math, see http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/grapher-equation.html and try some of the examples. I just took the square root of x and tweaked the function until it mostly matched your line. I edited the jsfiddle in my answer with some more lines as an example.